# How to create dates of a particular month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate all the dates of a particular month starting from the 1st of that month to the 30 or 31st of that month with out using a trivial `for` loop:

```rb
for i in 1..Time.days_in_month(Date.today.month, Date.today.year)
  date = Date.new(y, m, i)
end
```

I was getting dates like this but I'm not supposed to use this trivial for loop.

Comment: show us how you was trying to do it and may we can help you

Comment: Have you looked at `Date` and `Range`? Should be fairly straight forward from there.

Comment: Can you please provide with a particular link?

Comment: `Date.current.all_month.to_a` should work, see [`all_month`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_month)

Comment: FWIW: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html

Comment: "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)" is useful.

Answer (score 7):

Although there are quite a few ways you could accomplish this, one way would be to use a Ruby [`Range`](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/06/ruby-ranges-how-do-they-work) combined with the [`Time#beginning_of_month`](https://apidock.com/rails/Time/beginning_of_month) and [`Time#end_of_month`](https://apidock.com/rails/Time/end_of_month) methods to generate an object that contains all of the days of the month and then convert it into an array:

```rb
(Date.today.beginning_of_month..Date.today.end_of_month).to_a
=> [Fri, 01 Nov 2019, Sat, 02 Nov 2019, Sun, 03 Nov 2019, Mon, 04 Nov 2019, Tue, 05 Nov 2019, Wed, 06 Nov 2019, ...., Fri, 29 Nov 2019, Sat, 30 Nov 2019]
```

Another option would be to use the [`Time#all_month`](https://apidock.com/rails/Time/all_month) helper which is as simple as:

```rb
Date.today.all_month.to_a
=> [Fri, 01 Nov 2019, Sat, 02 Nov 2019, Sun, 03 Nov 2019, Mon, 04 Nov 2019, Tue, 05 Nov 2019, Wed, 06 Nov 2019, ...., Fri, 29 Nov 2019, Sat, 30 Nov 2019]
```

Answer (score 2):

(Plain Ruby) The Date class uses negative numbers as a way of counting from the end (like in Arrays):

```
require "date"

today = Date.today
m, y  = today.month, today.year
p (Date.new(y,m,1) .. Date.new(y,m,-1)).to_a
```